# Determining if object property is empty

Tags: php

I feel like I'm missing something here. I've been using PHP's `empty()` function for quite a while now in determining if a variable is empty. I wanted to use it to determine if an object's property is empty, but somehow it doesn't work. Here's a simplified class to illustrate the problem

```
// The Class 
class Person{
    private $number;

    public function __construct($num){
        $this->number = $num;
    }

    // this the returns value, even though its a private member
    public function __get($property){
        return intval($this->$property);
    }
}
```

---

```
// The Code    
$person = new Person(5);

if (empty($person->number)){
    echo "its empty";
} else {
    echo "its not empty";
}
```

So basically, the `$person` object should have a value (5) in its number property. As you might have guessed, the problem is that php echoes "its empty". But it's not!!!

However, it does work if I store the property in a variable, then evaluate it.

So what would be the best way to determine if an object property is empty? Thank you.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue, and the cause was scope.  It's because the property is declared private.  If it were protected or public it would work as expected.  In my case there really wasn't a reason to make the property private so I changed scope.

Answer (score 26):

You need to implement [__isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) magic method.

> __isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties.

```
public function __isset($property){
    return isset($this->$property);
}
```

Comment: I love it when I post an answer that is correct, but someone posts an answer that is more correct. +1

Comment: Years passed. PHP doesn't get fixed. Even PHP's "null coalescing operator" works the same way.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (empty(($person->number)))

/* OR */

if (!isset($person->nothing) || empty(($person->nothing)))
```

Putting () around the Object->Property value will force it to be evaluated prior to calling empty.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Person::$number

Comment: @BradKent, Because of the evaluation you are getting a notice for trying to use an undefined variable (property value). If there is any possibility that your property is possibly going to be null/undefined you'll want to check isset first. 

    (!isset($person->nothing) || empty(($person->nothing)))

Answer (score 1):

Check if the return value is `null` instead. Should give you the right answer.